# Laravel locale route get

Tags: php, laravel

Normaly i use
`Route::get('{locale}/home', [MachineController::class, "home"]);`

But i want to use the $locale variable to set the language

```
Route::get('{locale}/home', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale(getLocale($locale));
    [MachineController::class, "home"];
});
```

but that returns an empty page, whats the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: You can use route group with a middleware

Comment: Move `App::setLocale(getLocale($locale));` into your `MachineController::home()` method.

Comment: as sta has said, this is a good job for a middleware ... if you find yourself in a route action/controller calling another controller, usually you are going about it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem with the code you written.

MVC structure ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) defined that you must write `App::setLocale(getLocale($locale));` in home method from MachineController class ([Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing)).

or you can define your route like below:

```
Route::get('{locale}/home', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale(getLocale($locale));
    (new MachineController())->home();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you issue with you code try this way :

```
Route::get('{locale}/home', function ($locale) {
    $current=getLocale($locale);
    App::setLocale($current);
    (new MachineController())->home();
});
```